# Android Emulator is restored to last state when started from "Cold Boot Now"

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-studio-4.1

Android Studio 4.1

I closed an emulator and then I started it again using "Cold Boot Now" but it just restored to previous state when it should have booted the system from scratch

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's known issue. Looks like it [was fixed](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/10/android-studio-42-canary-15-available.html) in 4.2 Canary 15.